# How do I use JSON with Sqlite on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sqlite

I am trying to get data from my sqlite database on rails using JSON but I don't know how to. I already did all the scaffolding. what gems do you recommend and how do I used them with an exiting project from sqlite database.
I have a web application that has users and all the users that are created are stored in the sqlite database. I need to retrieve this information and show it on a page where it could look something similar to this.

[{
    "Manufacturer": "Toyota",
    "Sold": 1200,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "Ford",
    "Sold": 1100,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "BMW",
    "Sold": 900,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "Benz",
    "Sold": 600,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "GMC",
    "Sold": 500,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}, {
    "Manufacturer": "HUMMER",
    "Sold": 120,
    "Month": "2012-11"
}]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Can you please include an example of what you are trying to do or a least a more specific description.

Comment: If you put in the code for your model it becomes easier to give you function code. However, you can use the `to_json` method that ActiveRecord models have.

Comment: do you mean the schema?

Comment: You just want to show it on a page? You're saving it in the DB as json? How are you planning to deploy? Sqlite won't work on heroku. You'll need to use something like postgres or mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those objects are saved in a model called `Cars`, and that you have a `CarsController`, and you want to show in the `index`...assuming all of that...inside your cars controller's index action use active record and define an instance variable.

```
def index
  @cars = Car.all
end
```

Then in your index view file you can access that variable.

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
 <%= #### whatever you want to show %>
<% end %>
```

Need more info to help more than this.